# How to resolve JSF ViewExpiredException in clustered environment?

Tags: jsf-2

i am using JSF 2.0 and getting ViewExpiredException in Websphere clustered environment when page fail over from one server to another server. Appreciate if anybody assist on this.

Comment: this is myFaces security bug and it gets resolved by adding context parameters in web xml.     <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.secret</param-name>
        <param-value>xxxxxxxx</param-value>
    </context-param>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.MAC_SECRET</param-name>
        <param-value>xxxx</param-value>
    </context-param>

Answer (score 0):

this is myFaces security bug and it gets resolved by adding context parameters in web xml.  org.apache.myfaces.secret xxxxxxxx   org.apache.myfaces.MAC_SECRET xxxx  
Parameter values depends on which algorithm(DES/AES) you're using to encrypt. Prefer AES which is more secure and robust.